# int.Parse is not working with string value (System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format )

Tags: c#, .net

If a user inputs anything but a number I get Unhandled Exception:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Here's my code C# .NET:

```
private static int WeightIFeMale()
{
    Console.WriteLine("How Much Do You Weigh?", Environment.NewLine);
    int femaleWeight = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if 
        (0 >= femaleWeight && 80 <= femaleWeight)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Damn, how much crack are you smoking?", Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else if
        (81 >= femaleWeight && 110 <= femaleWeight)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What the ****, are you a midget *****?", Environment.NewLine);

    }        
    else if 
        (111 >= femaleWeight && 140 <= femaleWeight)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Holy shit, I have some protein bar coupons you can have!", Environment.NewLine);

    }
    else if 
        (141 >= femaleWeight && 160 <= femaleWeight)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bro you need to hit the Gym, ASAP!", Environment.NewLine);

    }
    else if 
        (161 >= femaleWeight && 200 <= femaleWeight)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Really!!!, can I hit the Gym with you?", Environment.NewLine);

    }
    else if 
        (201 >= femaleWeight && 240 <= femaleWeight)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you Have a small ****, Steroids are a mother @#$%^&&", Environment.NewLine);

    }
    else if 
        (241 >= femaleWeight && 999 <= femaleWeight)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My condolences!", Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else if 
        (femaleWeight >= 1000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There is absolutely no way that you weigh {0} lbs, so stop ******* around!", femaleWeight, Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("What the **** is {0} It has to be a number numb nuts, lets try that again!", Environment.NewLine);
        WeightIFeMale();
    }

    return femaleWeight;
}
```

Comment: You need to be specific about the data that you are entering, and the broader context of the call (what's entered before, how is the call made, etc.)

Comment: `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` => the input must be numeric to be successfully parsed, otherwise it throwing error. Consider using `int.TryParse` instead.

Comment: OT once you have tested for `femaleWeight <= 80`, you don't have to test for `femaleWeight >= 81`

Comment: `0 >= femaleWeight && 80 <= femaleWeight` is `true` for a zero or negative weight ("0 is equal to or greater than ..") and at the same time at least 80. I'n not sure that will ever happen :-). Use `femaleWeight >= 0 && femaleWeight <= 80` for a weight between 0 and 80 inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `int femaleWeight = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

`int.Parse` method will throw `FormatException` if input can not be converted to integer.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Here when you providing value which is not seemed like a number value int.Parse() can't Parse it as INT. See this article [Int32.Parse Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) and see the **Exceptions table** [FormatException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx) description. So, 1. better you have a try catch functionality. Try the following suggestion , it is working. 2. Also You can use the    int.TryParse method

**Way 1.** Remove this statement  `int femaleWeight = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` of code with try catch statement.

```
   private static int WeightIFeMale()

        {
            Console.WriteLine("How Much Do You Weigh?", Environment.NewLine);
            //int femaleWeight = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string weigt_st = Console.ReadLine();
            int femaleWeight = 0;
            try
            {
                femaleWeight = int.Parse(weigt_st);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            if (0 >= femaleWeight && 80 <= femaleWeight)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Damn, how much crack are you smoking?", Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else if (81 >= femaleWeight && 110 <= femaleWeight)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What the ****, are you a midget *****?", Environment.NewLine);

            }

            else if (111 >= femaleWeight && 140 <= femaleWeight)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Holy shit, I have some protein bar coupons you can have!", Environment.NewLine);

            }

            else if (141 >= femaleWeight && 160 <= femaleWeight)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bro you need to hit the Gym, ASAP!", Environment.NewLine);

            }
            else if (161 >= femaleWeight && 200 <= femaleWeight)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Really!!!, can I hit the Gym with you?", Environment.NewLine);

            }
            else if
                (201 >= femaleWeight && 240 <= femaleWeight)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Do you Have a small ****, Steroids are a mother @#$%^&&", Environment.NewLine);

            }
            else if
                (241 >= femaleWeight && 999 <= femaleWeight)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("My condolences!", Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else if
                (femaleWeight >= 1000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There is absolutely no way that you weigh {0} lbs, so stop ******* around!", femaleWeight, Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("What the **** is {0} It has to be a number numb nuts, lets try that again!", Environment.NewLine);
                WeightIFeMale();
            }

            return femaleWeight;
        }
```

**Or Way 2.** Remove this statement  `int femaleWeight = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` of code with this one

```
   int femaleWeight = 0;
   int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out femaleWeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int femaleWeight;

if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out femaleWeight)) {
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter your weight in US pounds")
}
else if (...)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly!!!

Comment: Good answer but some one has down-voted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how it worked for me:

private static int WeightIFeMale()
    {
            Console.WriteLine("How Much Do You Weigh?", Environment.NewLine);
    } 
 int femaleWeight;

            if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out femaleWeight)) //I deleted the else statement.
    {
    Console.Write("What the **** is {0} It has to be a number numb nuts, lets try that again!", Environment.NewLine);
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        WeightIFeMale();
    }
    else if 
        (femaleWeight >= 0   && femaleWeight <= 80)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Damn, how much crack are you smoking?", Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else if
        (femaleWeight >= 81 && femaleWeight <= 110)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What the ****, are you a midget *****?", Environment.NewLine);

    }        
    else if 
        (femaleWeight >= 111 && femaleWeight <= 140)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Holy ***, I have some protein bar coupons you can have!", Environment.NewLine);

    }
    else if 
        (femaleWeight >= 141 && femaleWeight <= 160)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bro you need to hit the Gym, ASAP!", Environment.NewLine);

    }
    else if 
        (femaleWeight >= 161 && femaleWeight <= 200)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Really!!!, can I hit the Gym with you?", Environment.NewLine);

    }
    else if 
        (femaleWeight >= 201 && femaleWeight <= 240)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you Have a small ****, Steroids are a mother @#$%^&&", Environment.NewLine);

    }
    else if 
        (femaleWeight >= 241 && femaleWeight <= 999)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My condolences!", Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else if 
        (femaleWeight >= 1000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There is absolutely no way that you weigh {0} lbs, so stop ******* around!", femaleWeight, Environment.NewLine);
    }
```